# Solana program for daily SPL token airdrop

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter, airdrop

I am planning for an SPL token launch and would like people to visit my React app to claim the token on a daily basis.

What I am wondering is how much of the logic should go into the Solana program and what steps it would have to go through. From there, how would I call the program from the frontend. In my mind, I would pass the wallet address from the wallet adapter into the program, which would check if the wallet has claimed today, if it has a token account, make one if not etc.

Thank you